# Changing my xap name in windows phone app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I have created a new project called `Graphics` and I coded it and submitted the app to windows market place. But it seems that the term `Graphics` term is very generic and for that reason my app got failed. They have mentioned it to change the XAP name.

Are there any ways to do it?

Comment: Rename the project (maybe also the solution) from Visual Studio.

Comment: @Prætorian: I have did that. But it is producing the XAP with the old name.

Comment: Right-click on the project name, select *Properties*, the *Application* tab has an edit box containing the XAP file name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double click on `properties` in your `solution explorer` and click on `Application` tab on the left. Change the required details. `Xap file` name, `Title` and other options which you want to change.

Answer (score 3):

Find your app's WMAppManifest.xml file.

and change the Title Node in App.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your app's display name in the WMAppManifest.xml, which is under the Properties of the project.